# Removing window header using tidesdk

Tags: tidesdk

I want to remove the header of a **child** window using TIDESDK. I don't know how to use xml settings for a child window. I was successful in creating tiapp.xml file for the parent. Now, I am trying to use the Ti.UI.UserWindow APIs to remove the borders but to no avail.

Here is my unsuccessful piece of code:

```
var window1 = Ti.UI.createWindow('app://src/filename.html');
window1.setUsingChrome(false);
window1.setSize(400,200);
window1.setTransparency(0.5);
```

Every other property is accurately getting applied but the 'setUsingChrome' property shows no effect. Can someone advice how to use this property or to create a tiapp.xml file for tidesdk so as to remove the header from the **CHILD** window

Answer (score 0):

YESSss....found out finally, but realized after finding that it was kind of silly not to try this earlier.

```
var window1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({

  url: 'app://src/client/notifications/notifications.html',
  title: "Reminders",
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  maximizable: false,
  minimizable: false,
  closeable: false,
  resizable: false,
  fullscreen: false,
  maximized: false,
  minimized: false,
  usingChrome: false,
  topMost: true,
  visible: true,
  transparentBackground: false,
});
```

Setting either the transparentBackground property or usingChrome property removes the header and the borders(if present).